# Users in a company can only view projects within their company in Rails..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I have three models: users, organization, and projects.

Organization has_many users (with different roles) and users belong_to organization.

Users has_many projects, and projects belong_to both users and organizations (by putting `@project.organization_id = current_user.organization_id` in the `def create` method of the controller).

I put this bit in my `projects_controller.rb` file to make sure that users who are logged in can only view the projects that are associated with their organization.

```
def index
    @projects = Project.where(organization_id:current_user.organization_id)
end
```

However, all this does is hide the other projects from the current_user. If he types in http://localhost:3000/projects/3 (a project that belongs to another user from another organization) he's still able to access it.

What should I put in the `def show` part of projects_controller to stop this from happening?  I've hacked around a couple of things but I can't get it right without any errors. Also I'd like to not use CanCan if possible.

I tried putting a

```
before_filter :require_project_belong_to_organization, :only => [:show]

def require_project_belong_to_organization
   @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
end
```

but this is only returning a result if it was the user that created it. I need other users to be able to view it too, as long as they're in the same organization.

Answer (score 1):

Try [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Is it possible to do it without CanCan though?

Comment: At least the stop access part. I'm not sure if the 'all_resources_this_user_can_access_from_this_model' is in there too.

Comment: All right. I bit the bullet and went with CanCan. It's too little of a thing to spend too much time over!

Comment: @Reactormonk how do you did this with cancan as im trying to do the same thing?? thank you.

Comment: @Frank004 it's been 4 years, and cancan seems to be discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Use a before_filter in you controller and check if the project's user is the same as the current_user

Comment: It's not the project's user that I'm concerned about, it's the project's organization_id that has to be the same with the current_user's organization id.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make a function `authorized?` in the project model. Make sure that `current_user` is available to the model.

```
authorized?
  self.organization_id == current_user.organization_id
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  if @project
    unless @project.authorized?
      flash[:danger] = 'not authorized'
      redirect_to.... 
    end
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Project was not found'
  end
end
```

Comment: There are gems like [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) that make this approach much easier.